# How to validate dropdown list using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

When I  submit the button without selecting any option then I display error. It works.But the issue here when I hit submit after selecting any option then error remains. I am unable to remove error if option is selected.

```
selected.Can anyone help me please

<form id="myForm">     
  <select  id="logs" data-placeholder="Type here to find device"
            name="tags[]"
            multiple
            class="chosen-select form-control"
            required>
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="ASA"     > ASA     </option>
    <option value="ISE"     > ISE      </option>
    <option value="Windows" > Windows  </option>
    <option value="ATA"     > ATA      </option>
    <option value="Alliance"> Alliance </option>
    <option value="Proxy"   > Proxy    </option>
    <option value="Csp"     > CSP      </option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  <p id="loggingError" style="color: red; font-size: small;"></p>
</form>
```

```
var logs = document.getElementById('logs');
var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');

function loggingCheck(event)
{
  if (logs.selectedIndex == 0 )
  {
    document.getElementById('loggingError').innerHTML="Please select at least one logging devices";
    event.preventDefault();
  }
  else
  {
    document.getElementById('loggingError').innerHTML="";
  }
}

myForm.addEventListener('submit',loggingCheck);
```

Comment: You have to listen for changes, because this code only works on click. You should use the onChange function to listen to changes for the select box.

Comment: You have wrong condition `logs.selectedIndex == 0` should be `logs.selectedIndex < 0`

Comment: witch message ?  the loggingError message or the "system form select" automatic message ? on Firefox or Chrome ? (or?)

Comment: I added a management of the submit event to show you that it is not called in case of error in the entry

Comment: why didn't you validate any of the answers? none is suitable?

Answer (score 0):

```js
var logs = document.getElementById('logs');
var myForm = document.getElementById('myForm');

function loggingCheck(event) {

  if (logs.value === '') {
    document.getElementById('loggingError').innerHTML = "Please select at least one logging devices";
    event.preventDefault();
  } else {
    document.getElementById('loggingError').innerHTML = "";
  }
}

function changeCheck(event) {
  if (event.target.value !== '') document.getElementById('loggingError').innerHTML = "";
  else document.getElementById('loggingError').innerHTML = "Please select at least one logging devices";
}

myForm.addEventListener('submit', loggingCheck);
logs.addEventListener('change', changeCheck);
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <select data-placeholder="Type here to find device" id="logs" name="tags[]" multiple class="chosen-select form-control">
    <option value="ASA">ASA</option>
    <option value="ISE"> ISE</option>
    <option value="Windows"> Windows</option>
    <option value="ATA">ATA</option>
    <option value="Alliance"> Alliance</option>
    <option value="Proxy"> Proxy</option>
    <option value="Csp"> CSP</option>
  </select>
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  <p id="loggingError" style="color: red; font-size: small;"></p>
</form>
```

Comment: Hii, Thanks for your reply. Its not working..Its even showing me an error my i select any option..

Comment: Well, by your logic it meant the first option should not be selected. In that case, you need to introduce either a faux option in the beginning or the edited answer.

Comment: Actually, when hot submit  if user is not selected any option I want to display error and prevent submitting form but if after that he select the any option then I want to remove the error and submit the form. .

Comment: The updated answer should concern your problems. The code of my previous edit wasn't working because of the required tag in the html. It doesn't let the code reach the on submit. Also, checking for empty value is cleaner.

Answer (score 0):

The selectedIndex is -1 instead of 0

```
var logs = document.getElementById("logs");
var myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");


function setError(id, message) {
  var error = document.getElementById(id);
  if(error) {
    error.innerHTML = message || "";
  }
}

function loggingCheck(event) {
  if (logs.selectedIndex < 0) {
    setError("loggingError", "Please select at least one logging devices");
    event.preventDefault();
  } else {
    setError("loggingError", "");
  }
}

myForm.addEventListener("submit", loggingCheck);
logs.addEventListener("change", loggingCheck);
```

Adding a change handler will let you detect when a user selects one of the select's options. I'm reusing your loggingCheck method since, but break it out into a separate function if you want to validate the rest of the form's fields.

Comment: It seems to work on codepen [link](https://codepen.io/wombat42/pen/PoPeqaW?editors=1011) but perhaps you want what @Mister_Jojo is doing instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the `required` attribute and want to use your own messages, you must manage the [reportValidity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement/reportValidity) and [setCustomValidity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLObjectElement/setCustomValidity) methods

```js
const myForm = document.getElementById('my-form')

myForm['tags[]'].oninvalid = evt =>
  {
  evt.target.setCustomValidity('Please select at least one logging devices')
  }
myForm.oninput = evt =>
  {
  //  if (evt.target.name==='tags[]') ...
  evt.target.setCustomValidity('')
  evt.target.reportValidity()
  }
myForm.onsubmit = evt => // if the form has error the submit event doesn't happen
  {
  evt.preventDefault()
  console.log('the form is now supposed to be submitted...')
  setTimeout(() => { console.clear() }, 2000) // clear log about 2s;
  }
```

```css
input:invalid { border-color: crimson; }
```

```html
<form id="my-form">

  <select name="tags[]"  multiple required size="7">
    <option value="ASA"     > ASA      </option>
    <option value="ISE"     > ISE      </option>
    <option value="Windows" > Windows  </option>
    <option value="ATA"     > ATA      </option>
    <option value="Alliance"> Alliance </option>
    <option value="Proxy"   > Proxy    </option>
    <option value="Csp"     > CSP      </option>
  </select>

  <button type="submit">Submit</button>

</form>
```